# How to modify your SQL so it only returns one instance of each primary key?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Help with "Cannot insert duplicate key in object error";

We have 2 data extensions, the target DE has a PK for email address and the source DE has multiple instances of users submissions. I am getting the "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_C1A760D747B0422FB941A2E240A7B92D'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object" error. In essence, i just want the most recent submission from a particular user in the Source De to update the target DE.
this is my query:

```
SELECT EmailAddress as SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, CurrentBlue, CurrentRed, registered_date 
FROM Quiz_NewResults 
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, registered_date, Getdate()) = 1 
    AND GreenType is null
```

Comment: Can you just confirm you meant SQL and not SOQL? Someone "corrected" it but marketing cloud uses only SQL unless I am mistaken.

Comment: SQL sir, i thought the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to dedupe and get the last submission.

See here sample. (Am using SQL partitioning ROW_NUMBER to get the last instance of that email address)

```
select W.EmailAddress as SubscriberKey, W.EmailAddress, W.CurrentBlue, W.CurrentRed, W.registered_date FROM
    ( SELECT  EmailAddress, CurrentBlue, CurrentRed, registered_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by EmailAddress order by registered_date DESC) as 'n'
    FROM Quiz_NewResults 
        WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, registered_date, Getdate()) = 1 
            AND GreenType is null ) W
    where W.n=1
```